# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type

Tags: flutter

I am trying to fetch data from backend and store it in my app. However when I am using method to fetch it i am facing this error  `Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'StartChapter'`. Is my model set up wrong or the fetching function is written wrong? Can someone advice me something? Thanks

Method that fetches data:

```dart
  Future<List<Adventures>> getAdventureList() async {
    var response = await getAdventures(apiClient);
    return List<Adventures>.from((response.data["collection"]).map((json) => Adventures.fromJson(json)));
  }
```

I am trying to fetch data from my backend, example JSON looks like:

```json
{
   "collection":[
      {
         "completed":true,
         "creator_id":"4b94b85f-696e-4682-9534-572d1b2bc47f",
         "creator_nick":"master_of_adventure69",
         "description":"go on a wonderful adventure through the streets of the old town ...",
         "favorite":true,
         "id":"ffcc3fad-8bc2-4ba3-9b8e-59d77b2bff23",
         "name":"The best adventure in the world",
         "start_chapter":{
            "completed":true,
            "description":"at this point you must demonstrate extraordinary intelligence ...",
            "id":"5130dd90-9738-4a26-aeea-10d7d9c905b5",
            "name":"first point in adventure",
            "position":{
               "lat":53.01379,
               "lon":18.598444
            },
            "question":[
               {
                  "chapter_id":"5130dd90-9738-4a26-aeea-10d7d9c905b5",
                  "description":"What has a tail and barks?",
                  "id":"3718f6a9-fff1-4a15-9a24-ae3fa90b4141",
                  "sort":1,
                  "type":"tip/question"
               }
            ],
            "radius":500,
            "ridle":{
               "answer":"42856",
               "id":"ce8545e6-eeca-41c0-9026-9084df5aad13",
               "type":"number_lock_5"
            },
            "tips":[
               {
                  "chapter_id":"5130dd90-9738-4a26-aeea-10d7d9c905b5",
                  "description":"What has a tail and barks?",
                  "id":"3718f6a9-fff1-4a15-9a24-ae3fa90b4141",
                  "sort":1,
                  "type":"tip/question"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   "page":1,
   "page_size":50,
   "total_pages":1
}
```

Model

```dart
class Adventure {
  List<Adventures>? collection;
  int page;
  int page_size;
  int total_pages;
  int total_results;

  Adventure({ this.collection, required this.page, required this.page_size, required this.total_pages,
     required this.total_results });

  factory Adventure.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Adventure(
      collection: json['collection'].map((item) => Adventures.fromJson(item)).toList(),
      page: json['page'],
      page_size: json['page_size'],
      total_pages: json['total_pages'],
      total_results: json['total_results']
    );
  }
}

class Adventures {
  bool completed;
  String creatorId;
  String creatorNick;
  String? description;
  bool favorite;
  String id;
  String name;
  StartChapter startChapter;

  Adventures(
      {required this.completed,
      required this.creatorId,
      required this.creatorNick,
        this.description,
      required this.favorite,
      required this.id,
      required this.name,
      required this.startChapter});

  factory Adventures.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Adventures(
        completed: json['completed'],
        creatorId: json['creator_id'],
        creatorNick: json['creator_nick'],
        description: json['description'],
        favorite: json['favorite'],
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name'],
        startChapter: json['start_chapter']
    );
  }
}
and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a already StartChapter model and 'fromJson' method,
try to change like below.

```
class Adventures {
  bool completed;
  String creatorId;
  String creatorNick;
  String? description;
  bool favorite;
  String id;
  String name;
  StartChapter startChapter;

  Adventures(
      {required this.completed,
      required this.creatorId,
      required this.creatorNick,
        this.description,
      required this.favorite,
      required this.id,
      required this.name,
      required this.startChapter});

  factory Adventures.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Adventures(
        completed: json['completed'],
        creatorId: json['creator_id'],
        creatorNick: json['creator_nick'],
        description: json['description'],
        favorite: json['favorite'],
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name'],
        startChapter: json['start_chapter'] != null ? StartChapter.fromJson(json['start_chapter']) : null
    );
  }
}
```

If not, define 'fromJson' into the StartChapter class.
Or change startChapter's type from 'StartChapter' to 'Map<String, dynamic>' class.

```
class Adventures {
  bool completed;
  String creatorId;
  String creatorNick;
  String? description;
  bool favorite;
  String id;
  String name;
  Map<String, dynamic> startChapter;
...
```

Comment: Hm getting this message `The argument type 'StartChapter?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>`

Comment: May I know what you modified?

Comment: exactly like you did, tried, also tried changing type from  `'StartChapter' to 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

Comment: You choose only one modification. If 'fromJson' method is defined in StartChapter, you choose first modification. If not, choose second modification.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/M87c89QT

Comment: You've already have a 'fromJson' method in StartChapter class. So you just modify like this . ' startChapter: json['start_chapter'] != null ? StartChapter.fromJson(json['start_chapter']) : null'
Although you changed attached link, is there error?

Comment: I've changed it to `Map<String, dynamic> startChapter;` and it works, that should be fine?

Comment: I think attached link would better way. maintain StartChapter type and using 'fromjson'. startChapter: json['start_chapter'] != null ? StartChapter.fromJson(json['start_chapter']) : null

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because you are passing `wrong` data type value to the `variable`.

`start_chapter` accepts type of `StartChapter` but you are passing Map here :

```
"start_chapter":{
            "completed":true,
            "description":"at this point you must demonstrate extraordinary intelligence ...",
            "id":"5130dd90-9738-4a26-aeea-10d7d9c905b5",
            "name":"first point in adventure",
            "position":{
               "lat":53.01379,
               "lon":18.598444
            },
            "question":[
               {
                  "chapter_id":"5130dd90-9738-4a26-aeea-10d7d9c905b5",
                  "description":"What has a tail and barks?",
                  "id":"3718f6a9-fff1-4a15-9a24-ae3fa90b4141",
                  "sort":1,
                  "type":"tip/question"
               }
            ],
            "radius":500,
            "ridle":{
               "answer":"42856",
               "id":"ce8545e6-eeca-41c0-9026-9084df5aad13",
               "type":"number_lock_5"
            },
            "tips":[
               {
                  "chapter_id":"5130dd90-9738-4a26-aeea-10d7d9c905b5",
                  "description":"What has a tail and barks?",
                  "id":"3718f6a9-fff1-4a15-9a24-ae3fa90b4141",
                  "sort":1,
                  "type":"tip/question"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
```

You need to pass data type of `StartChapter` to solve this issue.

Use below model :

```
import 'dart:convert';

Adventure adventureFromJson(String str) => Adventure.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String adventureToJson(Adventure data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Adventure {
    Adventure({
        this.collection,
        this.page,
        this.pageSize,
        this.totalPages,
    });

    List<Collection> collection;
    int page;
    int pageSize;
    int totalPages;

    factory Adventure.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Adventure(
        collection: json["collection"] == null ? null : List<Collection>.from(json["collection"].map((x) => Collection.fromJson(x))),
        page: json["page"] == null ? null : json["page"],
        pageSize: json["page_size"] == null ? null : json["page_size"],
        totalPages: json["total_pages"] == null ? null : json["total_pages"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "collection": collection == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(collection.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "page": page == null ? null : page,
        "page_size": pageSize == null ? null : pageSize,
        "total_pages": totalPages == null ? null : totalPages,
    };
}

class Collection {
    Collection({
        this.completed,
        this.creatorId,
        this.creatorNick,
        this.description,
        this.favorite,
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.startChapter,
    });

    bool completed;
    String creatorId;
    String creatorNick;
    String description;
    bool favorite;
    String id;
    String name;
    StartChapter startChapter;

    factory Collection.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Collection(
        completed: json["completed"] == null ? null : json["completed"],
        creatorId: json["creator_id"] == null ? null : json["creator_id"],
        creatorNick: json["creator_nick"] == null ? null : json["creator_nick"],
        description: json["description"] == null ? null : json["description"],
        favorite: json["favorite"] == null ? null : json["favorite"],
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
        startChapter: json["start_chapter"] == null ? null : StartChapter.fromJson(json["start_chapter"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "completed": completed == null ? null : completed,
        "creator_id": creatorId == null ? null : creatorId,
        "creator_nick": creatorNick == null ? null : creatorNick,
        "description": description == null ? null : description,
        "favorite": favorite == null ? null : favorite,
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "name": name == null ? null : name,
        "start_chapter": startChapter == null ? null : startChapter.toJson(),
    };
}

class StartChapter {
    StartChapter({
        this.completed,
        this.description,
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.position,
        this.question,
        this.radius,
        this.ridle,
        this.tips,
    });

    bool completed;
    String description;
    String id;
    String name;
    Position position;
    List<Question> question;
    int radius;
    Ridle ridle;
    List<Question> tips;

    factory StartChapter.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => StartChapter(
        completed: json["completed"] == null ? null : json["completed"],
        description: json["description"] == null ? null : json["description"],
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
        position: json["position"] == null ? null : Position.fromJson(json["position"]),
        question: json["question"] == null ? null : List<Question>.from(json["question"].map((x) => Question.fromJson(x))),
        radius: json["radius"] == null ? null : json["radius"],
        ridle: json["ridle"] == null ? null : Ridle.fromJson(json["ridle"]),
        tips: json["tips"] == null ? null : List<Question>.from(json["tips"].map((x) => Question.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "completed": completed == null ? null : completed,
        "description": description == null ? null : description,
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "name": name == null ? null : name,
        "position": position == null ? null : position.toJson(),
        "question": question == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(question.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "radius": radius == null ? null : radius,
        "ridle": ridle == null ? null : ridle.toJson(),
        "tips": tips == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(tips.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Position {
    Position({
        this.lat,
        this.lon,
    });

    double lat;
    double lon;

    factory Position.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Position(
        lat: json["lat"] == null ? null : json["lat"].toDouble(),
        lon: json["lon"] == null ? null : json["lon"].toDouble(),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "lat": lat == null ? null : lat,
        "lon": lon == null ? null : lon,
    };
}

class Question {
    Question({
        this.chapterId,
        this.description,
        this.id,
        this.sort,
        this.type,
    });

    String chapterId;
    String description;
    String id;
    int sort;
    String type;

    factory Question.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Question(
        chapterId: json["chapter_id"] == null ? null : json["chapter_id"],
        description: json["description"] == null ? null : json["description"],
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        sort: json["sort"] == null ? null : json["sort"],
        type: json["type"] == null ? null : json["type"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "chapter_id": chapterId == null ? null : chapterId,
        "description": description == null ? null : description,
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "sort": sort == null ? null : sort,
        "type": type == null ? null : type,
    };
}

class Ridle {
    Ridle({
        this.answer,
        this.id,
        this.type,
    });

    String answer;
    String id;
    String type;

    factory Ridle.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Ridle(
        answer: json["answer"] == null ? null : json["answer"],
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        type: json["type"] == null ? null : json["type"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "answer": answer == null ? null : answer,
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "type": type == null ? null : type,
    };
}
```

Comment: why there is so many null checks? Also when I add this code I see red errors everywhere that parameter cant be null

Comment: the null checks are there so that if you get null value your code can handle that and for parameter can't be null you need to make fields nullable like List<Collection>? or  int?.